# "Unsparsing" numpy Arrays with Given Masks

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, sparse-matrix

Suppose there are two arrays, `vals` contains values, and `masks` contains booleans indicating whether to use the values in `vals`, or `nan`s. The goal is to build an array `ret` of the same length as `masks`, containing the values from `vals` in corresponding locations to `True` entries in `masks`.

For example, suppose

```
vals = np.array([1, 2])
masks = [True, False, False, True]
```

Then `ret`, the return value, should be

```
array([1, None, None, 2], dtype=object)
```

---

This is obviously very easy to do using loops:

```
import numpy as np

def unsparse(vals, masks):
    vals_i = 0
    ret = []
    for m in masks:
        if m:
            ret.append(vals[vals_i])
            vals_i += 1
        else:
            ret.append(None)
    return np.array(ret)

>> unsparse(np.array([1, 2]), [True, False, False, True])
array([1, None, None, 2], dtype=object)
```

Is there a way to do so without loops and more concisely?

Comment: Do you really want the `None` in that array?  Are you going to do any calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this -

```
out = np.empty(masks.shape,dtype=object)
out[masks] = vals[:masks.sum()]
```

Please note that `:masks.sum()` selects first `N` elements from `vals`, where `N` is the number of `TRUE` elements in masks.

If it's guaranteed that the number of TRUE elements is same as number of elements in `vals`, then you could just simply do -

```
out[masks] = vals
```

Sample run -

```
In [34]: vals = np.array([1, 2, 6, 8, 9])
    ...: masks = np.array([True, False, False, True, False, True])
    ...: 

In [35]: out = np.empty(masks.shape,dtype=object)
    ...: out[masks] = vals[:masks.sum()]
    ...: 

In [36]: out
Out[36]: array([1, None, None, 2, None, 6], dtype=object)
```